# TextView Drawable compat returns null

Tags: android, textview

My TextView has Drawable icon associated with it as below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProfile"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_menu_profile" />
```

while trying to tint/colour at runtime the textView's drawable compact, the below attempt returns null. But, the `android:drawableLeft` returns the drawable instance.

```
tvProfile.compoundDrawables[0]?.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Was wondering any solution with `android:drawableStart`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **`compoundDrawablesRelative`** method:

```
tvProfile.compoundDrawablesRelative[0]?.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

You can check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawablesRelative()):

> Returns drawables for the `start`, `top`, `end`, and `bottom` borders.

while the `getCompoundDrawables` returns drawables for the `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` borders.

Comment: What is the differences between `Relative` and regular CompoundDrawable?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like this on kotlin:

```
fun TextView.setDrawableColor(@ColorRes color: Int) {
      compoundDrawables.filterNotNull().forEach {
          it.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this code actually do?